# Does adverse-selection have a time-frame associated with it?

Tags: trading, limit-order-book

When my limit order gets filled, the price almost always moves against me due to adverse-selection. However, given 'enough' time the price may yet move back in my favour.

Has there been any study into the extent of adverse-selection at various timescales?

Answer (score 3):

No, it varies with product and is heavily conditional on your entry. Your experience is to be expected, adverse selection is often just sufficiently large enough to deter you from improving your execution prices by turning a liquidity-taking strategy into a BBO-pegging strategy, i.e. arbitrage-free between peg order and marketable crosses.